Expected length of guessing game: is next higher/lower than previous, uniformly drawn numbers
Question
Let's play the following game. To begin with, draw a real number $X_0$ between $0$ and $1$ uniformly. Then we continue drawing numbers $X_1, X_2, \dots$ (from $U(0,1)$) and each time we must guess whether the next number is smaller or bigger than the previous. This is of course done optimally: if $X_n < \frac{1}{2}$, we guess bigger and otherwise smaller. The game ends when we guess incorrectly. Call the index of the last number the length of the game. What is the expected length of this game?

My try
Let's denote by $f_n$ the continuous part of the "distribution" of $X_n$ being some value and the game not having ended (there's also the discrete part that the game has ended). Then
$$
f_n(x) = \int_0^1 K(x,y)f_{n-1}(y)dy
$$
where $K(x,y) = 1 - \large 1_{x<\frac{1}{2}}\large 1_{y<x} - \large 1_{x>\frac{1}{2}}\large 1_{y<x}$.
By symmetry, $f(x)=f(1-x)$ and for $0\leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$
$$
f_n(x) = 2 \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}f_n(t)dt - \int_0^x f_n(t)dt
$$
Here are the first few
$$ \begin{aligned}
f_0 &= 1 \\
f_1 &= -x+1 \\
f_2 &= \frac{1}{2} x^{2} - x + \frac{3}{4} \\
f_3 &= -\frac{1}{6} x^{3} + \frac{1}{2} x^{2} - \frac{3}{4} x + \frac{13}{24} \\
f_4 &= \frac{1}{24} x^{4} - \frac{1}{6} x^{3} + \frac{3}{8} x^{2} - \frac{13}{24} x + \frac{25}{64} 
\end{aligned}$$

Interesting observation: the numerators of the constant terms appear to be A105796 in OEIS
And that has actually led me to the hypothesis
$$
f_n(0) = \frac{1}{n!2^{n-1}}\sum_{j=0}^{n}j!S(n,j) \tag{1}
$$

Let's call the length of the game as $L$. Now using the formula $\mathbb E [L] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathbb P(L>n)$ and noticing that $\mathbb P(L>n)$ is the constant coefficient of $f_{n+1}$ and also that the sum of those up to $n$ is stored in $f_{n+1}$ when we "plug in" $-j!$ for $x^j$ (which integration from $0$ to $\infty$ against $e^{-x}$ achieves) I believe we have
$$
\mathbb E [L] + 1 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} f_n(-x) dx
$$
That integrand appears to be like a gaussian curve centered somewhere around $n$. So maybe if we can find its parameters, we can calculate the limit. I mean some kind of closed formula with maybe $e$ and such. A numerical value can of course be already calculated accurately since those probabilities we're adding go to zero fast. The value is
$$
\mathbb E [L] \approx 3.6934844987231
$$
With the hypothesis (1) above, I managed to get this result:
$$
\mathbb E [L] = -1 + \sum_{n=1} \frac{1}{n!2^{n-1}} \sum_{j=0}^n j!S(n,j) = \frac{2}{2-\sqrt e} - 2
$$

By law of iterated expectation, isn't $ E = \frac{1}{2} \times 1 + \frac{1}{2} ( 1 + E ) $ and thus $ E = 2$? Put another way, what's the expected number of coin flips till you get a Tails?

No...it's more interesting than that. If the current $X$ is $0.9$ and you guess that the next one will be lower, your odds of being right are $90%$, not $50%$ as with heads/tails.

Have you tried a simulation? My simulation yields $E[L]\approx 3.7$. Perhaps one of us is off by $1$.

@quasi Yes that's what I originally had too but when writing the question I thought defining the length of the game this way would decrease it by one, but it doesn't. If the first guess is incorrect the game length is still $1$. I'll fix my numbers.

I managed to solve it!
Denote by $T$ the operator from $L^2 [0,1]$ to itself taking the function $f$ to the function that is defined for $x \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ as
$$
Tf(x) = 2\int_0^\frac{1}{2} f(t) dt - \int_0^x f(t)dt
$$
and for $x \in (\frac{1}{2}, 1]$ by the symmetry $f(x) = f(1-x)$.
Then
$$
\mathbb E [L] = \int_0^1 (I-T)^{-1}f_0 (t) dt
$$
where $I$ is the identity operator and $f_0 = 1$. This is because the probability $\mathbb P(L>n)$ is given by $\int_0^1 T^n f_0(t) dt$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty T^n = (I-T)^{-1}$.
So we need to solve
$$
(I-T)f = f_0.
$$
Taking derivative we get that $0 = f'(x) + f(x)$ so $f(x) = Ce^{-x}$. And we can solve $C$ from the equation $1 = f(0) - 2 \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} f(t)dt$. We get the solution
$$
f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{e}}{2-\sqrt{e}} e^{-x}
$$
which gives the answer
$$
\mathbb E [L] = \int_0^1 f(t) dt
= \frac{2}{2-\sqrt{e}} - 2.
$$

I noticed we get the same answer if the random numbers are gaussian: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/knybhb1rb9  Does it hold for any (symmetric?) distribution?

Well not for all, since for (finite sided) dice rolls the answer is different, in fact a rational number. But as the number of sides grows, we approach the continuous uniform case. On the other hand if we take more and more dice of same size, we approach the gaussian case.
